# Convert to blob and from blob in Node.js

Tags: node.js, image, pdf, blob

I need to create pdf file, put image in it, save it and place in the DB. I ave an image in blob, I must convert it to proper image before placing it into my pdf. I also must convert pdf into blob before placing it in my DB.

I create pdf with 'pdfkit' module.

I can't understand how I should convert blob to image and pdf to blob. Need your help!

This is how I create pdf:

```
doc = new pdf;
      doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('app.pdf'));
      doc.text(rows.firstName + ' ' + rows.lastName + ' ' + rows.image);
      doc.end();
```